# How do I require a json file with requirejs and save it as a list?

Tags: javascript, json, requirejs

I tried

```
const some_variable = require(['C:/Users/Admin/some_folder/something.json']); 
const the_list_i_want_to_save_in = JSON.parse(some_variable);
```

And got the error

```
 Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

I searched here for similar questions and noticed that the u is because some_variable is "undefined". So how do I properly load in the json file and why is it undefined in this case? Never used requirejs before so I don't know how it works.

Comment: What are you getting in `some_variable` ? Can you please post that.

Comment: You need a json plugin for RequireJS in order to require the JSON files